# How to handle file delete after returning it has response in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am performing the below steps in my DRF code.

1. Capturing the file name in a request
2. Searching the given file name in a SFTP server.
3. If the file is available in SFTP server,downloading it to local path in a folder called "downloads"
4. Returning the file as response with FileResponse

I need to delete the file which i downloaded from SFTP or simply delete everything in downloads folder.

What is the best approach to achieve this?
How about an async celery task before returning FileResponse?

Comment: what have you tried? you can remove a file using ```os.remove(file_path)```

Comment: @shivankgtm i am aware of it, but if i do that before returning FileResponse, the file will get deleted rite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to use the Python module [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html), which provides temporary files which are automatically deleted when all references in Python are removed.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```py
>>> import tempfile

# create a temporary file and write some data to it
>>> fp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
>>> fp.write(b'Hello world!')
# read data from file
>>> fp.seek(0)
>>> fp.read()
b'Hello world!'
# close the file, it will be removed
>>> fp.close()
```

Once you have this file object, you can use [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) to send it back to the client.

An alternate way would be to use a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to delete files [older than a certain number of days](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/).

Comment: Nice, will there be any difference if we ourself write a file and keep writing data into it only against tempfile(python) ?

Comment: @shivankgtm You can use the file object created by tempfile just like a file object created by `open()`. If you also need the file to have a name, then the NamedTemporaryFile is needed.

Comment: Is there any particular command to create a temp file?

Comment: @SivaPerumal I've added a code example on how to create a temp file.

Comment: @Nick ODell two questions return FileResponse("what is the code here") And if uss fp.close() before return FileResponse  will rhe file object will persist?

Comment: @SivaPerumal 1) You give the FileResponse the temp file. e.g. `FileResponse(temp_file)`. 2) If you close the file, it will be deleted. So don't close the file. FileResponse will close the file. The FileResponse documentation says, "The file will be closed automatically"